# How to launch a product from terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-service-catalog

I have a Product in my AWS Service Catalog that I would like to create a terraform script that will launch the product. I am probably missing something obvious but I can't see an obvious way of doing this from the docs. Any helpers and pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like support for products has been added to the provider yet. Referencing the open PR here:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/4980

Looks like there's quite a bit of work around adding more Service Catalog functionality.

Comment: Thanks @EFeit. I'll need to look into alternatives to do this